# How is force applied from one object to another calculated?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

For example, I have a force of $3\ \text{N}$ accelerating a $1$ kg block $A$ on a frictionless surface to the right.
$A$ accelerates at a rate of $3$ $\text{m/s}^2$. Say it collides with another block $B$, weighing $2$ kg.

What is the force applied on $B$? I would have thought it would be equal to the acceleration of $A$ ($\text{3m/s}^2$) multiplied by the mass of $A$ ($1$ kg). However, that would mean a force of $3\ \text{N}$, which would then cancel out due to Newton's third law and stop the entire system from moving. Furthermore, what is the acceleration of $B$ after this force is applied?

I edited a previous question to ask this question but it hasn't been opened so I'm posting again.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. Do you mean that A and B stick together and then move with the same acceleration? Or that a constant force (presumably 3N) is being applied both before and after the blocks have become joined?

Comment: @JohnRennie After A comes into contact with B, they keep moving together with the force of 3 N still being applied on A.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid being lost in Newtonian mechanics, follow these steps:

- Define clearly your system.
  In your example, you have the choice between A, B, and (A+B)
- Identify all the **external** forces applied to your system.
- Check if the mass of the system is constant. You cannot directly apply
  Newton's second law if it is not the case.
- Check if your system is a rigid body. If it is not the case, you must calculate the position of its center of mass.
- Apply Newton's laws:$$  \sum_i  \overrightarrow{ F_{i} } =m.   \overrightarrow{ a } _{cm}$$

$$ \sum_i    \tau _{i}  =I \frac{d \omega }{dt}  $$
Identify the unknowns: $$ \overrightarrow{a} , \omega ,  \overrightarrow{ F }_{contact}$$
The contact forces like the normal force, the friction forces, etc... are never known before hand. One must eliminate them from the equations (by combination), solve for the acceleration and then calculate them once we know the acceleration.

To come back to your problem:

**Before the collision:**

- **System: A**
- External applied force: F
- Newton's second law: $ a= \frac{F}{m}=3 m/s^{2}$
- **System B:**
- F=0, a=0

**During the collision:**
A new contact force must be taken into account. B exerts the force $ F_{B/A}$ onto A and A exerts the force $ F_{A/B}$ onto B.

- **System: A**
- External applied force:  $ F_{B/A}$, $F$
- Newton's second law: $ F-F_{B/A}=m_{A}.a_{A}$
- **System: B**
- External applied force: $ F_{A/B}$
- Newton's second law: $ F_{A/B}=m_{B}.a_{B}$

Newton's third law allows us to simplify a little bit the problem by eliminating one of the contact forces.

$$ F_{A/B}=-F_{B/A}=f$$

But we still have two equations with three unknowns: $ a_{A}, a_{B}, f $.
$$\begin{cases}F-f=m_{A}.a_{A}\\f=m_{B}.a_{B}\end{cases} $$

Let's see if we can find a new equation by considering the system A+B.

- **System: A+B**
- External forces: F.$ ( F_{A/B}$ and $F_{B/A}$ )are internal forces.
- Rigid body: no. The position of the center of mass of the system is changing. It is given by:$$\begin{cases} x_{cm}= \frac{m_{A}x_{A}+m_{A}x_{B}}{m_{A}+m_{B}} \\v_{cm}= \frac{m_{A}V_{A}+m_{A}V_{B}}{m_{A}+m_{B}}\\a_{cm}= \frac{m_{A}a_{A}+m_{A}a_{B}}{m_{A}+m_{B}}\end{cases} $$
- Newton's second law:  $ F= \big(m_{A}+m_{B}\big) a_{cm}$

You may think, you have enough equations to solve the problem. Unfortunately, it is not the case, the equation:  $ F= \big(m_{A}+m_{B}\big) a_{cm}$ is not independent of: $$\begin{cases}F-f=m_{A}.a_{A}\\f=m_{B}.a_{B}\end{cases} $$
Indeed by adding member wise, we get:
$$ 0=F-f+f=m_{A}.a_{A}+m_{B}.a_{B}=\big(m_{A}+m_{B}\big) a_{cm}$$

At this point, you can already answer your question.
During the collision, the force applied to B is different from the force applied to A.
$$F_{/A}=F-f$$ and $$F_{/B}=f$$

Even if the external force F is null during the collision, you cannot use the acceleration prior to the collision to calculate the force on B.
$F_{/B}=f=-m_{A}.a_{A}$ **where $a_{A}$ is the acceleration during the collision (not $ a= 3 m/s^{2}$).**

At last, the acceleration of B after the collision is null. As soon as the contact between A and B breaks off, the force f disappears.

But can we solve the problem and calculate the motion of A and B after the collision. We still have two equations and three unknowns, so we can't. To go any further, one needs more information about the collision process. In introductory mechanics courses, one generally assumes the collision to be elastic (e=1) or inelastic with a coefficient (e<1). That is enough to calculate the velocities of A and B after the collision. But to calculate the force of interaction one further needs the duration$ \triangle t$ of the collision. The force acting onto B during the collision is then given by:
$$ f \approx  m_{B}\frac{ \triangle V_{B}}{ \triangle t} $$

Answer (score 0):

If the two bodies remain in contact they have a mass of 3kg with a 3N force applied. The joint system will therefore accelerate at 1m/s^2.

The block A will experience the original force of 3N and an opposite reaction force of 2N from block B. The net force is therefore 1N and it will accelerate at 1 m/s^2

Block B will experience a force of 2N from A and will therefore accelerate at 1 m/s^2

Comment: I know they can be treated as one object with a total mass of 3kg, however if we treat them separately we should still get the same result. Why does A experience a force of 2N from B and exert a force of 2N onto B, when A has an acceleration of $3m/s^2$ and a mass of $1$ kg? Shouldn't this result in A exerting a force of 3N onto B?

Comment: Once they are in contact A only has an acceleration of 1m/s^2, not 3 m/s/^2. The set of forces are consistent with both A and B having the same acceleration of 1m/s^2.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the answer. Why does A only have an acceleration of 1m/s^2 after they come into contact though? In other words, how is the normal force of 2N calculated?

Comment: The momentum transfer would be: $\Delta P = - 2\mu V_A$ [assuming initial velocities $V_A > 0$ and $V_B = 0$ and $\mu = m_1m_2/(m_1+m_2)$], the exact force depend n the rigidity of the bodies and the time in which this momentum transfer is made.

Comment: Assuming they remain in contact, they will both accelerate at 1 m/s^2 (3 N applied to 3 Kg).  Therefore mass A must have a net force of 1N acting on it; this requires a reaction force of 2N from mass B.  Mass B must have a force of 2N acting on it to accelerate at 1 m/s2.  This is also consistent with Newton's third law of equal and opposite reactions between the two bodies.